# ubuntu IPTables

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, tcp

I started hosting my game-server on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 I am having an issues ، some enemies/bug abusers log in 2+ characters in the same second then they spam a certain spell/word that lags/stops my game-server is it possible to make an IPTables for TCP connections on port "7171" to kick/bypass if 2+ characters logged in from the same IP at the same second/time and is it possible to make other one when a number of spells/words spammed per second by players on same IP they get kicked?

"Someone hosting the same game-server on Linux have already done it but he isn't welling to share his IPTables rules ، He did when 2+ players log in from the same IP at the same second they get kicked after 60 second without blocking" Thanks in advance I appreciate anyone's help/answer

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: That was what I was wondering.  It's a fair question; I know it's possible, but I haven't touched `iptables` in years.  It's pretty trivial in `pf`, but I don't think it would help this fellow.

Comment: so it isn't possible to be done? I am not alright with the normal "Drop-Reject" they block the IP for a long time, I just want them to masskick/bypass after the connection has been made within some seconds.

Comment: Clearly it _is possible_ because you yourself tell us another server operator has solved the problem. Please give us time - this isn't a paid service and we help if we choose to do so.

Comment: I am sorry, take your time. Thanks for your interest/answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 7171 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 --connlimit-mask 32 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

This will `REJECT` all connections above 1 from the same ip to port 7171

See more in [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html)

Comment: some players use multi client to make team-war etc.. that will make it hard for them :/